# jQuery text extraction method not extracting text from HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this div:

```
<div class="panel-body" id="result-body">
      <p id="para">blah blah blah</p>
</div>
```

And this jQuery listener:

```
$('#result-body').ready(function(){
  alert("Text: " + $("#para").text());
});
```

I was expecting this to alert me with

> Text: blah blah blah

but it only alerts with

> Text:

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: use $(document).ready(

Comment: @AnoopJoshi I did. Same issue.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3908050/3evw1wt3/

Comment: console.log($("#para").length);

paste this code to your browser console and run.Check what it outputs or is there any error or not.

Comment: @AbhisekMalakar Interesting that it outputs 0

Comment: I think you might have another element with the same id.\

Comment: What do you see when you press F12 and look at the console?  Any errors?

Comment: Seems odd. If it possible then please give the link to inspect your code snippet.Because the html you provide is not matching the result.And also ione possibility may that your P#para is appending in your dom with ajax.

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 alert("Text: " + $("#para").text());
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="panel-body" id="result-body">
      <p id="para">blah blah blah</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope that the code is fine. 
http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=SqIKJ4TBUD

It may be the problem with Jquery reference. Try to host the Jquery file in the same server that you running the HTML file.

Else use standard reference

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe in your html page you have two or more elements with id="para" ?

With you're current code, maybe you would like alert("Text: " + $("#result-body #para").text()); ?